# ASp.Net Link button click event is not fired,

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is a very strange scenario,

Suppose, I browse my site like "http://web.site.com" this way. my site display perfectly my Home page, on this page on the top, i am using one user control and this user control is displaying a logout Link button.

case 1:
When i click this button in this scenario then its does not fired,

Case 2:
But if i open my site like "http://web.site.com/default.aspx" then its work correctly and fired.

Can any one suggest me on this?

the below control is using in user control

```
<asp:linkbutton id="logoutLinkButton" runat="server" 
         onclick="logoutLinkButton_Click1">logout</asp:linkbutton>
```

and the Link button event code is

```
protected void logoutLinkButton_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             var url = this.Request.RawUrl;
             Authentication.Logout();
             Response.Redirect(url); 
         }
```

Comment: What is the code you have against that button ?

Comment: Check the logout link. I guess you are not using the login status control.

Comment: What url you have set to link?

Comment: Thanks to all i have edit my question and write the above code which i am executing

Comment: can you also give the html generated link tag on both scenario.

Comment: Check the html of link is it same on both occasions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using [Request.RawUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.rawurl.aspx)

> The raw URL is defined as the part of the URL following the domain
>   information. In the URL string
>   http://www.contoso.com/articles/recent.aspx, the raw URL is
>   /articles/recent.aspx. The raw URL includes the query string, if
>   present.

so for your case `"http://web.site.com"` `RawUrl` would be empty, and thus not doing anything. Instead you can use `Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)` like

```
protected void logoutLinkButton_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var url = this.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
   Authentication.Logout();
   Response.Redirect(url); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried your code also but its not working, even i have not written a simple line like "Response.Write("Test");
" but it's also no fired in this simple case, but if i pass the default.aspx on the url then its write "Test" on the page.

Comment: @Priyank, that is strange, where did you put the `Response.Write` in your code. Make it first statement of the event

Comment: i have only written Response.Write Statement in my click event. and its does not write if i not browse my site with default.aspx

Comment: I just want to say, Link button click event not fired, if i not use default.aspx. i don't think this is related to link button code.

Comment: @Priyank, I am not sure why it is behaving like that, can you clean/rebuild the solution and try again ?

Comment: As suggested, i have clean my solution and upload dll again, but no luck to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Request.URL' instead of`Request.RawUrl`

Comment: no its still not working, even if i written only "Response.write("Test") instead of all code then is not write on the page.